# accumulative accounting sum sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, sql-like

I´m having problems with a solution for what looks easy but for me it isn't, I'm loosing my mind on this one and I hope you guys can help-me:

First problem its to sum the different values as a balance from the analytical accounts to the sintetic ones in a accumulative way. ex:
account # 1 it's the sum of 1.1, receiving the values from the sum of 1.1.10 and 1.1.20 and so on.

The seccound problem worries me the most, creating  a new account under another!

Supposely if I want to create an account under another one if the superior one is an analytical one, i have to set a due_date for this one create two other accounts: one  sintetic with the same number and no due date and the actual analytical one under it, transfering the values by doing a debit and credit between them.
to better see if have and account X -  2.1.1.20.05 analytical  with 200.00
got to create another             Y - 2.1.1.20.05 sintetic 
entry a debit off 200.00 on X
then create the actual account Z - 2.1.1.20.05.01 analytical 
and a cretid of 200.00

That was messing the balance and trying to solve the problem I've divided the values on active and inactive ones but I´m not getting the results I was looking for.

This is my query and right below the script to create and simulate my problems.

Thanks in advance!

```
    select test.account_number,test.account_type, test.id, Start, Debit, Credit , (Start +( Credit + Debit )) balance  
      from ( SELECT accounts.account_number,accounts.account_type, accounts.id, DATEPART(yy,entrie_date) [Year],
                   --DATEPART(mm,entrie_date) [Month], 
                    SUM( CASE WHEN entrie_date < '2015-02-01' THEN VALUE  ELSE 0 END) [Start], 
                    SUM( CASE WHEN (Map.value < 0 )  and (Map.entrie_date between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28') THEN Map.value ELSE 0 END) [Debit],
                    SUM( CASE WHEN (Map.value > 0 )  and (Map.entrie_date between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28') THEN Map.value ELSE 0 END) [Credit]    
              FROM accounts 
              left join (select accounts.account_number,accounting_entries.value,entrie_date 
                          from accounts 
                          inner join accounting_entries on (accounting_entries.account_id = accounts.id)
                         ) Map ON RTRIM(LTRIM(Map.account_number)) like RTRIM(LTRIM(accounts.account_number)) + '%' 
    where accounts.account_number like '2%' 
    GROUP BY accounts.account_number, accounts.account_type, accounts.id,DATEPART(yy,entrie_date)--,DATEPART(mm,entrie_date) 
           ) test            
    order by 1,2,3
```

Script

USE [Test]
        GO

```
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[accounts]    Script Date: 11/16/2015 11:12:54 PM ******/
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[accounts]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[accounts]    Script Date: 11/16/2015 11:12:54 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[accounts](
        [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [account_number] [nchar](20) NULL,
        [account_type] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [start_date] [date] NULL,
        [due_date] [date] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_accounts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO


    USE [Test]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[accounting_entries]    Script Date: 11/16/2015 11:13:12 PM ******/
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[accounting_entries]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[accounting_entries]    Script Date: 11/16/2015 11:13:12 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[accounting_entries](
        [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [account_id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [entrie_date] [date] NOT NULL,
        [value] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_accounting_entries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('1', 'SINTETIC',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('1.1', 'SINTETIC',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('1.1.1', 'SINTETIC',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('1.1.1.10', 'SINTETIC',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('1.1.1.90', 'SINTETIC',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('1.1.2', 'SINTETIC',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('1.1.2.30', 'ANALYTICAL',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('1.1.2.92', 'ANALYTICAL',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('1.1.3', 'SINTETIC',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('1.1.3.10', 'ANALYTICAL',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('2', 'SINTETIC',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('2.1', 'SINTETIC',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('2.1.1', 'SINTETIC',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('2.1.1.10', 'ANALYTICAL',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('2.1.1.20', 'SINTETIC',  '2014-01-07', null)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('2.1.1.20.05', 'ANALYTICAL',  '2014-01-07', '2015-02-28')
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('2.1.1.20.05', 'SINTETIC',  '2015-02-01', NULL)
    insert into accounts(account_number, account_type, start_date, due_date)
    values('2.1.1.20.05.01', 'ANALYTICAL', '2015-02-01', NULL)

    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (7, '2015-05-01', -500.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (8, '2015-01-01', 100.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (8, '2015-02-01', 200.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (5, '2015-01-01', -500.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (10, '2015-01-01', 100.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (10, '2015-01-01', 200.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (10, '2015-01-01', -500.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (14, '2015-01-01', 100.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (14, '2015-01-01', 200.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (14, '2015-01-01', -500.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (16, '2015-01-01', 100.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (16, '2015-01-01', 200.00)        
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (7, '2015-02-05', -500.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (8, '2015-02-02', 100.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (8, '2015-02-02', 200.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (8, '2015-02-02', -500.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (10, '2015-02-02', 100.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (10, '2015-02-02', 200.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (10, '2015-02-02', -500.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (14, '2015-02-02', 100.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (14, '2015-02-02', 200.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (14, '2015-02-02', -500.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (16, '2015-02-02', -300.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (18, '2015-02-02', 300.00)
    INSERT INTO accounting_entries(account_id, entrie_date, value)
    VALUES (18, '2015-02-02', 100.00)
```

[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PVUU.png)

Comment: First, I see a problem in your script. If you are summing for accounts under account 1, it will also include the value for account 1. I do not know if that is what you intended to do. Second, it is not clear why you want to create accounts. Is it a process you think will get you to the correct balances, or is it a requirement to create accounts/entries and then do the reporting. The way you describe creating accounts, you start with an analytical account and end up creating another analytical account with the same amount. It will be a never ending process. Please explain what you want.

Comment: Once you create an account the superior one has to be sintetic , but, because i need to keep the  history of my accounts in case i to report last month or last year of it,  that account has to remain the way it was so its entries, closing it with due date was the bets way to keep it intact,Sorry  about the script it doesn't create the data base just the table an some inserts.

Comment: I've posted an image of the results.. cant get the balance to go up on scale accounts!

Comment: Marisco, it is still not clear why you want to create accounts. Is that a requirement or do you think it is the correct way to move ahead?

Comment: Creating  accounts its optionaI, but imagine you have a  goverment accounts:  #1 banks ,  but at your company you wold prefer to controlled it in a more especific way, creating a 1.1 Santander, 1..2 Bank of America. 1.3 HSBC and so on.. thats why!

Comment: ok. For now let us think of a solution without creating accounts. You have accounts and you have account entries. Next, what do you want to see?

Comment: For tax  porpuse the goverment just wanna know whats your  full ammount in banks, but if the board wants to controll it better in a certain point, then that analytical  goverment ccount becomes sintetic and the others are created under it keeping it history.

Comment: So you have 2 requirements. 1. Tax Report for the government 2. Report for the board. Let us focus on them one by one. What is your solution for #1 and does it produce result according to your requirement?

Comment: the problem its comming when those 2 same # accounts has  entries at the same month!

Comment: What is the query you are using?

Comment: as you see in a imagige i have the account  total balance credits and debits so 1 analitic bank had a 1000 and created 1.1 Santander, and 1.2 Bank of america, if my report its before november that account has to have 1000 but from november  foward i need to have a sistetic 1, and lets say 500 each 1.1 and 1.2

Comment: the sum its killing me!

Comment: Marisco, relax. Go step by step. Are you still on the first question, the report for the government? or have you jumped on the second?

Comment: same question, as you sum the balance of the highest account cant be modified as you create new lower ones. i used at the script the account 2.1.20.05 to simulate it

Comment: We can sum up the accounts without creating new accounts. What exactly is your requirement? Is it possible to describe your requirement without including how to do it?

Comment: yes sum up the account is the first step.

Comment: What exactly is the requirement? Can you explain the complete requirement?

Comment: the requirement It´s to  show the fionantial movement form a  start balance, debist crecits and actual balance of my accounts in the company.  Lets say I received 10,000.00 to spend with an office  during a year, then I have to show each month where did that money goes, under the account office supply by sum up the debits and credits, under various accounts like, eletronics, paper, staff.. etc...

Comment: where is the information like electronics, paper, staff etc stored? I do not see it in any of the tables you have defined.

Comment: they represented by account # I just didn't add a description.

Comment: i know, its a complicated one... i realy apreciate your help Adish!

Comment: Marisco, Does your script to insert data contain data that has to be reported on, or does it also contain accounts you have added on your own?

Comment: it has both accounts and entries the account

Comment: SELECT accounts.account_number,DATEPART(yy,entrie_date) [Year],DATEPART(mm,entrie_date) [Month], SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE < 0 THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END)*-1 [Debit],SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE > 0 THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) [Credit]
FROM accounts 
inner join (select accounts.account_number,accounting_entries.value,entrie_date
            from accounts 
            inner join accounting_entries on accounting_entries.account_id = accounts.id) Map
ON RTRIM(Map.account_number) like RTRIM(accounts.account_number) + '%'
GROUP BY accounts.account_number,DATEPART(yy,entrie_date),DATEPART(mm,entrie_date)
order by 1,2,3

Comment: Marisco, see if the above query makes sense to you and takes you one step closer to what you need.

Comment: Very interesting way to group them,  I'll try to make it work in a way i can use, I'm posting a print of the actual report and point it out on it the problems. Maybe you get a better idea visualizing the problem!! Thanks Adish! I apreciate it!

Comment: Let me know how it goes. I am still positive you will not need to add records/accounts for any type of reporting.

Comment: Hey Adish! I have edit the script and query so you can have a better idea, notice that the credits, debits and balances are getting mixed up because of the date :( ....  this one matches the report print I've attached at the post. if you can  pls take a look! thank you!